# How to clone a record?

Tags: apex

I want to clone an existing account record. Is it possible using `.clone` in apex code? I need the data to be copied too.

I have an existing account(A) with values, when the user changes a particular field i want to create another account record(B) and copy all the values from A to B excluding the child records. Is this possible using Clone method? When tried using the clone method, i still had to give the name of the account, and none of the fields where copied, Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you have tried and where you are stuck? As your question is written, the answer seems to be an obvious yes.

Comment: I have an existing account(A) with values, when the user changes a particular field i want to create another account record(B) and copy all the values from A to B excluding the child records.  Is this possible using Clone method?  When tried using the clone method, i still had to give the name of the account, and none of the fields where copied,  Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that there is a standard way to [`clone`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) an `sObject` without cloning its relationship fields.  You can use the `deepClone` parameter to specify that you want the relationship objects to be cloned as well rather than just the reference, but they are still present on the object.

You could define a custom method to do this:

```
public void noRelationClone(sObject record, boolean preserveID, 
                            boolean preserveReadOnlyTimestamps, boolean preserveAutonumber)
{
    sObject recordClone = record.clone(preserveID, false, 
                                       preserveReadOnlyTimestamps, preserveAutoNumber);
    for(Schema.sObjectField field : recordClone.getSObjectType().getDescribe()
                                                                .fields.getMap().values())
    {
        if (field.getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Reference)
        {
            recordClone.put(field, null);
        }
    }
    return recordClone;
}
```

Note that I haven't tested the above.

Comment: i had to query the record before cloning, that what i was missing.  Thanks for the code illusiveBrian.